# Finding the number of solutions to two equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, affine-geometry, gaussian-elimination

I have a question:

For the following system of linear equations, using Gaussian elimination, decide whether it has at least one solution. If it does, represent the general solution as an affine map in matrix/vector form.

```
w + 3x - y + 2z = 1
-w - 3x + 2y - z = 2
```

Using Gaussian elimination i got:

```
w + 3x + 3z = 4
y + z = 3
```

Comment: Im not really following?

Comment: So if i pick z and x to equal 2?

Comment: Sorry im really not understanding

Answer (score -1):

I think you actually meant (Gauss reduction):

$$\begin{pmatrix}\;1&\;\,3&\!\!-1&\;2&\;\;1\\
\!\!-1&\!\!-3&\,2&\!\!-1&\;\;2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2+R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&3&\!\!-1&2&\;\;1\\
0&0&\,1&1&\;\;3\end{pmatrix}$$

The above reduced form mean:

$$\begin{align*}\text{Second line:}&\;\;y+z=3\implies y=3-z\\\text{First line:}&\;\;w+3x-(3-z)+2z=1\implies w+3x=4-3z\end{align*}$$

So you have two degrees of freedom: (choose freely the values of $\;z,x\;$ and then the values of *all* the variables get uniquely and completely determined.

Comment: Somebody didn't like my answer....hmm, I wonder why.

Comment: for the top row should it not be (1, 3, -1, 2)?

Comment: Yes, editing the typo, yet the way is correct.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer but why am i able to freely chose the values of z and x?

Comment: Well, in fact you can choose freely *any* two of those variables and then the other two are determined. I wrote $\;z,x\;$ because $\;y\;$ is already given *in my answer* as a function of $\;z\;$ (Though you can interchange the roles), and in the second equation I just choose one of the variables randomly...

Comment: How is this solution represented in as am affine map?

Comment: Uh? "Affine map"? What has that to do with all this at all? you may represent it as a set of vectors given by parametric equations.